# How to put a content inside the box after it has been hovered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm planning to make a sticky note kind of style and I want to show the content inside the box without it being displayed first when the hover is not active. Like here in my code example: Please help!

```css
body {
  margin: 45px;
}

.box {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 20px solid grey;
  background-color: violet;
}

.container:hover .box{
  transform: translate(200px, 150px) rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSSTransitions.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>CSS Transitions</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <p>Hello</p>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Hey guys, I'm sorry if my explanation of what I wanted to achieve wasn't clear. There's a pink box that is visible when not hovered and there's a violet box inside when it's hovered. I want the paragraph inside the violet box hidden when the pink box is not hovered. But my code shows here that even the pink box isn't hovered, the paragraph inside the violet box is already been displayed.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Could you edit the question to include a clearer explanation

Comment: Also, there appears to be no research effort applied here. Have you tried anything already to achieve the intended behaviour?

Comment: So you just want to reverse the current behaviour? i.e. have the pink `.box` element slide _in_ on hover instead of _out_?

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for my lack of explanation. I edited the description above to make it clearer for you guys of what I was trying to achieve. Thank you for your feedbacks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the **`position: absolute`** of the inside div i.e. **`.box`** to place it over the text. Remember to set **`position: relative`** to the parent div i.e. **`.container`**.

> ***Absolute*** positioned element is removed from the normal document flow; no space is created for the element in the page layout. Instead, it is positioned
>   relative to its closest positioned ancestor if any; otherwise, it is
>   placed relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is
>   determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left. This value
>   creates a new stacking context when the value of z-index is not auto.
>   Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins, and they do not collapse
>   with any other margins.
>
> [***More help on position property***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```css
body {
  margin: 45px;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 20px solid grey;
  background-color: violet;
}

.container:hover .box {
  transform: translate(200px, 150px) rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSSTransitions.css">
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>CSS Transitions</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanksss alot! Appreciate it! This is what exactly I was trying to achieve!

Comment: Glad to help :)